# If Make-up is Haram, is skin care Haram too?

Tags: halal-haram

Asalamu-alaykum,

I've read from this site that it is not allowed to wear make-up because it takes away the purpose of the hijab, but I wondered if skin-care does the same?

Say you don't like pimpled or seemingly just want clear skin, would it be considered haram because of how it might add to your beauty and cause attention?

Comment: Why would make be considered Haram? A lady is allowed to beautify herself for her husband. And make up is one of the means. What is recommended in Islam is to use the Hijab to hide one's beauty from Non-Mahram males inorder to avoid fitnah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you put it  , it sounds like Make-Up and Skin-Care are the same thing with different names.

I am not a woman so I will try to answer this question to the best of my knowledge.

But from the way I understand it, skin care is supposed to take care of your skin ;

Eg :

Prevent and cure pimples

Prevent and cure rashes, wounds etc. .

Moisten the skin. ...

The above examples do not serve to beautify you but to maintain your health, so I'd say they are permissible.

BUT make up is obviously Haram

Allah knows best

PS : I hope that the skin care product you are using is Halal  ( NO PIG ADDED )